# Setting Textbox Value with Button (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

What code would I use if I wanted to use a button to add a point (.) into a any selected textbox which already has a value in it. I can easily do this;

```
textField.text = @".";
```

But this only works with one text box and clears the value.

Comment: Need a little more explanation of what you're trying to achieve. If the textbox is selected can't you just press "." on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

`textField` doesn't mean any text field it is only connected to one.

If you have many variables referencing the text fields you have. just loop (using a for loop) through them and check for the one whose `editing` property is set to `YES`.

If you want to add a fullstop to the end of the text field's text use:

```
textField.text = [NSString stringByAppendingString:@"."];
```